# How to use S3 as storage for Loki logs?

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I am fairly new to Kubernetes, Helm and Loki.

I have deployed Loki-stack on my minikube cluster using Helm charts and I am trying to use S3 storage as storage for Loki logs.

I tried adding the following from the [documentation of Loki](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/examples/#s3-expanded-configyaml) to my custom chart and customizing it to my running S3 instance.

```
schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: 2020-05-15
    store: aws
    object_store: s3
    schema: v11
    index:
      prefix: loki_
storage_config:
  aws:
    bucketnames: bucket_name1, bucket_name2
    endpoint: s3.endpoint.com
    region: s3_region
    access_key_id: s3_access_key_id
    secret_access_key: s3_secret_access_key
    insecure: false
    sse_encryption: false
    http_config:
      idle_conn_timeout: 90s
      response_header_timeout: 0s
      insecure_skip_verify: false
    s3forcepathstyle: true
```

I made sure to customize the region, bucket names, endpoint, etc.
But Loki is not storing any logs whatsoever there. I would like some help to show me what I might be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432617/loki-config-with-s3

Answer (score 7):

I've been in your place. The soution I found was to use the Single Store Loki configuration [Single Store Loki (boltdb-shipper index type)](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/boltdb-shipper/)
. Also, I recomend you to use the common section to configure the shared_sotrage in an easier way and include the compactor configuration.

```
common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    s3:
      bucketnames: bucket-name
      region: aws-region
      access_key_id: Key
      secret_access_key: Secret

storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /tmp/loki/active
    shared_store: s3
    cache_location: /tmp/loki/cache
    cache_ttl: 24h

compactor:
  working_directory: /tmp/loki/compactor
  shared_store: s3
```

Comment: I found this very helpful, thank you.  One point to add:  if you are running Loki on an AWS EC2 instance as I am, you don't need to specify `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` in the config.  Instead, create an IAM role with appropriate permissions policy (see https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/#cloud-storage-permissions) and assign it to the EC2 instance.